# Should Firebase Auth with Javascript use HTTPS

Tags: javascript, firebase, https

First time I've begun using firebase with a JavaScript project:

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(creds.username, creds.password
```

Since it is connecting to Google via websockets, will the website need to be served over HTTPS to avoid a security vulnerability?

Comment: Even if it doesn't, consider serving over HTTPS anyway.  If you use things like Firebase Messaging, you will need HTTPS (since it uses a `serviceWorker` which requires HTTPS).  You can either host on firebase (which serves over HTTPS), or host anywhere and use a service like CloudFlare to provide a free SSL certificate for your domain (and sub-domains).

Comment: Thanks Raphael this was really helpful. I agree HTTPS is the way to go if possible. Was just curious if only using HTTP exposed user info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Firebase Auth makes a request to Google's backend servers, it does so over HTTPS and no email/password data is unencrypted in flight. You should still strive to use HTTPS on your own system, and if you're using Firebase already [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting) offers free static web hosting with SSL provisioning on your own domain.

Comment: Encrypt all the things! ☃